# How to mark all endpoints as @login_required

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am using flask-login plugin for my application, which is already developed to a good extent.

I want to mark all the url endpoints as "@login_required".

Is there any way I can do this in one place with a single line of code
rather than marking every view function with @login_required.

Comment: Since I am extensively using Blueprints, hence can be do something at the BP level, some api similar to add_url_rule

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own decorator. [Matt Wright's overholt template](http://mattupstate.com/python/2013/06/26/how-i-structure-my-flask-applications.html) provides an [example](https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt/blob/e03209f7a059d165a9154355d090738af3159028/overholt/frontend/__init__.py) that does exactly what you want.

```
from functools import wraps

from flask_security import login_required

def route(bp, *args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(f):
        @bp.route(*args, **kwargs)
        @login_required
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return f

    return decorator
```

You can [use this decorator](https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt/blob/e03209f7a059d165a9154355d090738af3159028/overholt/frontend/dashboard.py) to add routes to any endpoints used by the blueprint instead of using the blueprint's `route` decorator directly.

```
bp = Blueprint('name', __name__)

@route(bp, '/')
def route1():
    return 'Hello, world!'
```